# SearchView setSuggestionAdapter doesnt work as expected

Tags: android, android-actionbar, searchview

i have `SearchView` on the `ActionBar`and used `setSuggestionAdapter`on it to set the adapter for autocomplete.

problem is that when i type chars into the search view a popup list of suggestion does show but does not get filtered according to the string im typing, i always get the full underlying list in the adapter, is this the expected behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is the expected behavior. By setting a custom search adapter you are telling the SearchView that you want to override the default suggestions behavior and provide your own list of suggestions to the user.

This is useful in a number of situations, such as if you want to display the user's search history as a suggestion.

If you want to use the built in querying system for creating suggestions based on what the user is typing, you should create a search interface as described in the [Creating a Search Interface](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/search-dialog.html) documentation.